# Linq select one from groupby, take null or empty unless there is a number 1

Tags: c#, linq

Sorry about the awkward title, it's a simple problem with an added twist that I can't figure out how to handle. Say we have a list of objects (in this case, which parent to contact):

```
class Student
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Parent { get; set; }
    public string Order { get; set; }
}

List<Student> students = new List<Student>();
students.Add(new Student() { Id = "111", Parent = Grandma, Order=   });
students.Add(new Student() { Id = "111", Parent = Mom, Order = 1 });
students.Add(new Student() { Id = "111", Parent = Dad, Order = 2 });
students.Add(new Student() { Id = "222", Parent = Mom, Order = 1 });
students.Add(new Student() { Id = "222", Parent = Dad, Order = 2 });
students.Add(new Student() { Id = "333", Parent = Mom, Order =  });
students.Add(new Student() { Id = "444", Parent = Dad, Order =  });
```

My desired return values:

```
111 Mom
222 Mom
333 Mom
444 Dad
```

If it wasn't for the instances like student 111 I could use the Linq:

```
data.GroupBy(s => s.PupilNumber).Select(s => s.OrderBy(p => p.OrderBy)).Select(s => s.First()).ToList();
```

But this returns Grandma for student 111, where I want to return Mom. I can't clean out the null OrderBys, because then I would not get Mom and Dad for students 333 and 444.

Any ideas?

Comment: Your example code does not compile. Please fix it.

Comment: @Blorgbeard (Grumble) I proposed an edit that fixed the compilation errors but it was rejected for changing too much.  WTH??? I changed "Order = " to "Order = null" and fixed the lambda query so p => p.Order and PupilNumber became Id.  How could that have been rejected?

Comment: @MobyDisk I wasn't involved in your edit being rejected, but edits to fix code in questions are frowned upon, because the error could be part of the problem: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260245/when-should-i-make-edits-to-code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try forcing a null order to the bottom of the list with something like this:

```
students.GroupBy(s => s.Id).Select(s => s.OrderBy(p => p.Order ?? 9999)).Select(s => s.First()).ToList();
```

This is kinda cheesy, but it works.

Comment: int.MaxValue is better than using 9999.

Comment: In this context it won't change anything, but in general I try to avoid magic numbers, I've fought with too much of them. ;)

Comment: Shoot, I don't know who to mark as correct. Taking Moby Disk because I found the linq easier to read. I did have to make a slight adjustment because OrderBy is inconveniently a string.

Answer (score 1):

You could edit them up front with an arbitrary low priority:

```
data.Select(s => new { s.Id, s.Parent, Order = s.Order ?? int.MaxValue.toString() }).GroupBy(s => s.PupilNumber)...
```